# Pagination missing on category pages?

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, pagination

The pagination is missing on my toolbar on category pages, it works for the search results. I debugged the code and figured what the problem is.

In the Toolbar block there is a function `getPagerHtml`. It contains this code:

```
$pagerBlock = $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');

if ($pagerBlock instanceof Varien_Object) { 
    ... 
}
```

The problem in my case is, `$pagerBlock` is `false` on category pages in my case, so the pagination is never rendered and shown.

What could be the problem for that? I checked the catalog.xml and the `product_list_toolbar_pager` block is there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check your layout xml file (catalog.xml) of current theme

is block

`<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>`

really exist under 
`<catalog_category_default>` and `<catalog_category_layered>` handler ?

if this is exist then check other custom modules layout file for any overwriting.

Comment: Yes, it is really there. Ill diable some modules to see if that helps.